# Architectures/ABIs where sizeof(long long) != 8

Tags: c, abi

In x86/amd64 world `sizeof(long long)` is 8.

Let me quote quite insightful 8 year old [mail by Zack Weinberg](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2004-03/msg01251.html):

> Scott Robert Ladd  writes:
>
> > On a 64-bit AMD64 architecture, GCC defines `long long` as 64 bits, the
> >     same as a `long`.
> >
> > Given that certain 64-bit instructions (multiply) produce 128-bit
> >     results, doesn't it seem logical the `long long` be defined as 128 bits?
>
> No, for two reasons:
>
> 1. The choice of 64-bit '`long long`' has been written into the ABI of
>      most LP64-model operating systems; we can't unilaterally change it.
> 2. This is actually the correct choice, as it removes the aberration
>      that makes '`long`' not the widest basic integral type.  There is
>      lots and lots of code in the wild written to the assumption that
>      `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(size_t)` - this is at least potentially
>      broken by ABIs where long long is wider than long.
>
>    (This was an extremely contentious topic during the development of
>      C99.  As best as I can tell from an outside perspective, '`long long`' 
>      was only standardized due to pressure from Microsoft who can't for
>      some reason implement an LP64 model.  Everyone else hated the idea
>      of making '`long`' not necessarily the widest basic integral type.)
>
> Best current practice appears to be to provide an "extended integral
>   type" `__int128`.  This doesn't have the problems of '`long long`' because
>   it's not a *basic* integral type (in particular, it cannot be used for
>   `size_t`).
>
> zw

---

`long long` is widest **basic** integral type. It's 64-bit long on any non-dead-old architectures/ABIs I know. This allows for going with simple cross-platform (well, at least for many 32/64-bit architectures) typedefs:

```
typedef char               s8;
typedef unsigned char      u8;
typedef short              s16;
typedef unsigned short     u16;
typedef int                s32;
typedef unsigned int       u32;
typedef long long          s64;
typedef unsigned long long u64;
```

that are nicer than `intXX_t`, because:

- they use same underlying type for 64-bit integers on different platforms
- allows avoiding verbose `PRId64`/`PRIu64`
  (I am well aware that Visual C++ supports `%lld`/`%llu` only since 2005)

But how portable this solution is can be expressed by answers to the following question.

---

**What are the architectures/ABIs where `sizeof(long long) != 8`?**

If you cannot provide any recent/modern ones, then go ahead with the old ones, but only if they are still in use.

Comment: Btw, `typedef int s32` fails on implementations with a 16 bit `int`, of which there are a few microcontrollers kicking about. Obviously this has nothing to do with `long long`, which means that your plans for `s32` are irrelevant to the question you're asking :-) But I think you're more likely to trip over `s32` than `s64`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Sure. Question is about `long long` alone, but for usual purposes I am indeed concerned only about platforms where `char`, `short` and `int` are respectively 8-, 16- and 32-bit long.

Comment: Is it really common to assume `sizeof(long)>=sizeof(size_t)`? I've always assumed the opposite...

Comment: @dreamlax: I'm not familiar with that debate, but I assume that there was code around at the time that stored sizes and offsets in an `unsigned long`. I'm not sure that's actually much better style than whatever Windows code stores `long` in an `int`, that prevented MS implementing LP64. But C89 did in fact guarantee that `size_t` was an "integral type", and "integral type" in C89 meant just the basic ones required in the standard. So it was a breaking change that C99 allows `size_t` to be a bigger type than `unsigned long`, since C89 forbids it.

Comment: `long long` was not Microsoft's choice. It was standardized because of existing practice and the need for a 64-bit type on 32-bit systems where the prevalent ABI already had `long` as 32-bit.

Comment: The bar for portability, as I've seen it in the C community, is very high. It is: "will work on ANY system that conforms to the language specification." Technically speaking, the solution you propose is by definition "nonportable" -- there is no gray area about it, no "mostly portable" ideal that the community has generally accepted.

Comment: @OwenS.: As you've seen? Are you part of "the C community" or not? I am all for ideals, but convenience in programming matters too, and having same underlying type for same int-sized types across different platforms is part of it. It's not perfect approach, has its flaws, but works well on lot of systems. If I'll ever need to work with platform where it breaks, then I'll change my typedefs to use `intXX_t` and I'll fix call sites if needed (`printf()`, etc.). So if you want to prove me how wrong I am, at least mention these platforms, where it doesn't work. If their `long long != 8`, answer!

Comment: For an internal project where you know the platforms you're running on, I'd buy that. If you were planning to publish your code as an external library, be prepared for some push-back from the community. (I am in the neighboring C++ community, btw, which I suppose has a similar attitude about "mostly portable" constructs, though I have become used over the years to having to navigate the vagaries of compilers that don't meet the standards that I might want to write portable code for.)

Comment: @OwenS.: Fair enough. I'm also well aware of people strictly bound to standards. It's fine (I like to create standards compliant code too), but you have to be practical. If standard enforces me to write ugly code (like `PRId64` in the middle of split format string) I don't have to abide it as long as I know how to write better code for the platforms I am interested in deploying my project for. If standard is lacking some useful feature that I can find as "mostly portable" gcc (and hopefully clang too) extension, then I'll use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TI TMS320C55x architecture has `CHAR_BIT` of 16-bit and `long long` of 40-bit. Although the 40-bit `long long` violates ISO, `sizeof (long long)` is different from 8.

Actually nearly all the C99 implementations with `CHAR_BIT > 8` have  `sizeof (long long) != 8`.

TMS320C55x Optimizing C/C++ Compiler User’s Guide (2003)
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru281f/spru281f.pdf

Comment: Heh. Although the question clearly asks for `sizeof(long long) != 8`, I think based on the motivation that the questioner really wants to know about implementations where `long long` has a width other than 64 bits. I suppose it's possible that the questioner has already ensured `CHAR_BIT == 8` in the portability plan, for example by requiring Posix.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You're right. But I did not mention it in the question to get broader spectrum of answers, i.e. having more informative (thus interesting) thread here.

Comment: Should have renamed the type `slightly longer` to avoid ISO conflict.

Comment: Doesn't it make `sizeof(long long) == 40/CHAR_BIT == 2.5`?

Comment: @ugoren Actually `sizeof (long long) == 4` in this architecture. The remaining 24 bits are padding bits.

Comment: Sorry for late accept, but I was hoping to see more answers and more comprehensive ones too, but apparently no one was interested in it. Not that yours is bad, just there are surely many more examples of architectures that could be provided in such discussion.

Answer (score 0):

"(This was an extremely contentious topic during the development of C99. As best as I can tell from an outside perspective, 'long long' was only standardized due to pressure from Microsoft who can't for some reason implement an LP64 model. Everyone else hated the idea of making 'long' not necessarily the widest basic integral type.)"

It was contentious among Unix vendors, without reference to Microsoft, which had a lot of I16LP32 code, where the only 32-bit integer was long, so they plausibly did not want to change that.

UNIX & other vendors had ILP32 or like Amdahl, Convex, others ILP32LL64, so needed a 64-bit datatype, just as PDP-11s got to be IP16L32 in mid-1970s to get a 32-bit datatype instead of int X[2].

For the detailed history, here's 2006 article in ACM Queue, later reprinted in 2009 CACM. See especially Table 1.
"The Long Road to 64 Bits
Double, double, toil and trouble"
https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1165766
Also, if you read C99, I wrote the rationale for long long.
In the meetings described in the paper, we were split between:
IL32LLP64  - leave long as 32-bit
ILP64 - make ints and longs 64, introduce new type for 32
LP64 - make longs 64, leave ints 32
There were good arguments for each, but the argument was effectively settled by fact that the first two companies shipping 64-bit micros both went LP64.

Answer (score -1):

Your "cross-platform" typedefs are just misguided. The correct ones are

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int8_t s8;
typedef uint8_t u8;
typedef int16_t s16;
...
```

Comment: Apparently you missed the points of introducing these typedefs. I am well aware of `intXX_t`, heck I even referred to them. My solution is not intended to be "works everywhere" one (would be nice, though),  but "works on majority of used platforms". **But you are off-topic for an answer, referring to my introduction, yet leaving actual question unanswered.**

Comment: While it may not answer the question, I believe my answer addresses why the intended application of your question is misguided. It would have been hard to post just a comment given that I wanted to illustrate it with the actual typedefs.

Comment: Poor excuse. You could illustrate it in comment too, e.g. by writing "`typedef int8_t s8` and so on" and everyone would clearly understand you.